# Show <div> without JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very, very simple webpage, It consists of a large background image and a button in the centre of this image (the button is placed in a div to position it), I want this button to be clickable, and when clicked, replaced with ANOTHER div which will show a film trailer.

Every solution I come across implements JS and is to show/hide the div and does not replace the show/hide button.

I simply want to SHOW the div, it does not need to be hidden after (as the button will hopefully be replaced anyway).

Almost identical to this example on the Duke Nukem website : http://www.dukenukemforever.com/full/us/

When you click play trailer, it appears central. The only difference between this and what I want to do is I want my button to be central also, and show the trailer over the top of the button (with no ability to hide the trailer after it has begun)

If any one is wondering why I don't just put the trailer on the page and not bother with this is the reason for having it 'show' instead of just embedding the video in a div in the center of the page is that the webpage has a large background which I want to be visible first for impact, then show the trailer.

**if this is possible in JS and someone can show me an example, I would be open to that too!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`:target` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_the_:target_selector).

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/rgS2v/)

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate slightly?

Comment: this will only work in browsers that support this CSS3 selectors. Only the most recent version of IE does: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/sel_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this from straight HTML and CSS3 using the :target selector (which is only supported on the most recent of browsers). In the comments below SLaks show you an example if you follow the jsfiddle link.

There are many examples on the internet that will walk you threw showing / hiding a div onclick using JavaScript. Here is an example: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide

Comment: Wrong.  You can do this in pure CSS.

Comment: Learn something new everyday.

Comment: This won't work in IE 6,7,8 correct? I think only @font-face is supported by them.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use absolute positioning and z-index rules of css to display the div that shows the trailer on top of the first div, This can be done in javascript using the style property of the div element

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, if I used the z-index and placed one div over the other, but how could I hide the trailer div, until the button div is clicked?

Comment: you can hide it using the following css: display:none; and visibility:hidden

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use CSS with:

```
div.button:active {
   visibility:visible;
}
```

You could also use CSS expressions I'm sure, expressions, however, are deprecated and hardly supported.